# How to fix unity FormatException when parse from string to float?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, unity-game-engine

I have text file (presented as timeFile TextAsset). In this file i have string array, with float elements, one per row. Example:

```
7.9483900
8.392342
1.034224
0.032424323
23.563646346
```

So i'm split(\n), and every lines element have one float element.
And i have float array, with parsed lines.

But then i'm trying instantiate my prefab with y-position of this float array, I have:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   System.Number.ParseSingle (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) (at :0)

How to fix it?

```
void Start()
{
    var lines = timeFile.text.Split("\n"[0]);
    var linesFloat = new float[lines.Length];

    for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
    {
        linesFloat[i] = float.Parse(lines[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var position = new Vector3(0, linesFloat[i], -0.5f);
        Instantiate(projectilePrefab, position, Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0));
    }
}
```

I tryed `CultureInfo.InvarianCulture` in float Parse, but that didn't helped me.

Comment: None of the items you show here will fail to parse, so you haven't given us enough information to actually help. Does the string contain spurious characters? New lines or spaces for example? Blank lines? etc.

Comment: @DavidG, https://imgur.com/a/Pg4nXz3

Comment: Not helpful, that doesn't show hidden characters. Find out exactly which line is throwing the error. My guess is the very last line is blank. You may want to try `...Split(new[] { '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-check your input strings!

it is possible/likely that they still contain a `\r` character because windows (clrf) linebreaks are `\r\n` or maybe also a space character.

You could use [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) to make sure they are left out like e.g.

```
for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    linesFloat[i] = float.Parse(lines[i].Trim('\r', ' '), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

---

If you you only want to get rid of the exception you could use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) instead.

```
for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    if(float.TryParse(lines[i], out var floatValue))
    {
        linesFloat[i] = floatValue;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogFormat(this, "Oops value {0} could not be parsed!", lines[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Also note that you can simply use

```
var lines = timeFile.text.Split('\n');
```

if there is only one char